# how to write my jQuery code as a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on JQuery plugin and I am new at this,I have donw the following work:
code.js

```
var isstatic = false;
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".div-to-slide").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $(".show_hide").click(function () {
        $(".div-to-slide").toggle("slide");
        if (isstatic) {
            $("#myImg").attr("src", "/1.png");
            isstatic = false;
        }
        else {


            $("#myImg").attr("src", "/final-cropped.gif");
            isstatic = true;
        }
    });


});
```

everyhting is working in the code but I have been asked to make a jQuery plug in of this so that user writes a line and will be able to call this into his/her website.
I am a bit confused how to do it, what I have tried is this

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.recordsign = function () {
        var isstatic = false;
        $(".div-to-slide").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

        $(".show_hide").click(function () {
            $(".div-to-slide").toggle("slide");
            if (isstatic) {
                $("#myImg").attr("src", "/1.png");
                isstatic = false;
            }
            else {


                $("#myImg").attr("src", "/final-cropped.gif");
                isstatic = true;
            }
        });


    }
})(jQuery);
```

I have gone through some tutorials but dont know where to write $.extend,settings,options and other plugin specific code and then how to call it,at the moment I am calling it like this:

```
<a class="myclass" href="#">Function call</a>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.show_hide').recordsign();
});
```

I feel something is wrong,please take your time out to help on this.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: it's returning nothing. try `return isstatic = false;`

Comment: the code is working like above as well and I am able to call as well the problem is how can I change it so that i can use "this" etc in jquery plugin and other jquery specific codes like how to write this line  $(".div-to-slide").hide(); if i'm writing jquery plug in @K.C

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.myclass').recordsign();// .myclass not .ma
});
```

Also you need to focus on some points

1. Plugin for specific element: Your target element should be specific, so that you can use `this` as current object in your plugin.
2. Your image source should be dynamic, for this you can use `data-*` attribute to get it runtime.
3. `isstatic` should be passed by option, by default it can be `false`.

Comment: its typing mistake i think I have called it with .myclass.

Comment: I am working on the steps as u said will  $(".div-to-slide").hide(); be same in plugin?? you didnt say anything about  $(".div-to-slide").hide(); ??

Comment: If your targeted element contains `div-to-slide` element then your can refer my first point. Use `this` to find `div-to-slide` like, `$(this).find('div-to-slide')`

Comment: $(this).find('div-to-slide') is not working for me @Rohan Kumar

Comment: `div-to-slide` should be your child element of the targeted element and use `.` for class selectors like `$(this).find('.div-to-slide')`.

Comment: in my case in calling using .show_hide which is not parent element of  div-to-slide